# Session not available

Tags: java, jsp, session

In my JSP page, I am calculating session value as following

my.jsp Consists two buttons, one to submit the below form to upload.java and on click of another button leads to exec.java which does some command prompt execution stuff

my.jsp looks like,

```
<%
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy_HH:mm:ss:SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        timeStamp = timeStamp + ":" + System.nanoTime();
        String loc = "/u/poolla/workspace/FirstServlet/WebContent/WEB-INF/"+timeStamp;
        session.setAttribute("path", loc); // cal session and set attribute
%>

<div id="elements"> //form to accept files for upload
Left File :  <input type="file" name="dataFile1" id="fileChooser1" /></li>
Right File : <input type="file" name="dataFile2" id="fileChooser2" /></li>
Config File :<input type="file" name="dataFile3" id="fileChooser3" /></li>
Gc File :  <input type="file" name="dataFile4" id="fileChooser4" /></li>
<input type="hidden" id="myField" value="" /></li>
<button type="button" id="execute" onclick="ValidateFile()">Click to Upload files</button></li>
</div>

<Script>
ValidateFile()
{
 //Does some validation stuff and subvmits the form to upload.java
  document.myform.submit(); 
</Script>
```

upload.java

receive the session,

```
String fpath = request.getSession().getAttribute("path").toString();
```

Use commons file upload to upload files and send response to my.jsp

```
   RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("geco.jsp");
   rd.forward(request, response);// Access session set in my.jsp
```

Redirected to my.jsp,

on click of button 2, exec.java is started.

where, I need to access the session

```
try
    {
    String b = request.getSession().getAttribute("path").toString();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        b = "No value";
    }
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(b);
```

which is being printer as a null value, what to do?

From the below comments, 
I've learned that I am loosing session value on page refresh. Is there any way I can preserve the session value???

Comment: do you call anywhere request.getSession(true)???

Comment: Where are you setting the Session attribute?

Comment: @Deepak2221 in my.jsp, as shown in the above code.

Comment: @StefanBeike Yes, yet the same result.

Comment: I suggest you not using toString(). Try this: String b = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("path");

Comment: @StefanBeike Tried both bro :/ still the same error persists.

Comment: First check 
HttpSession session=request.getSession(false); what is it's value?

Comment: Just happens nothing, showin No value in output

Comment: it means your session is lost.

Comment: Oh! So you mean to say that I am loosing my session on page reload?

Comment: Is the time of the file upload bigger than the session timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to your comments above, I've understood that my session is getting refreshed.

So,

in my.jsp I've included stuff to check the existence of the session as shown below,

```
<%    
  String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy_HH:mm:ss:SSS").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
  timeStamp = timeStamp + ":" + System.nanoTime();
  HttpSession ses = request.getSession();
  if(ses == null || ses.getAttribute("path") == null)
{
  session.setAttribute("path", timeStamp);
}
  else
{
  session.getAttribute("path");
}
 %>
```

in Upload.java, I've received this session and added the received value back to the session again like this,

```
String fpath = request.getSession().getAttribute("path").toString();
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("path", fpath);

    //Did my file upload stuff using apache commons

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("my.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Finally, in mu exec.java after using the session I am invalidating it

```
HttpSession ses = request.getSession();
ses.invalidate();
```

Now, I am able to access the session even when the page is being refreshed.